# Two submit buttons in one HTML form, for uploading or deleting a file with PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, form-submit

I tried to create one form containing two `submit` buttons, one to upload a file and the second to delete a selected file from a specific location. The upload process is successful, but the delete process fails.

This is the code for the two `submit` buttons:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload and Delete file</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form action="upanddel.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select File to Upload:<input type="file" name="uploadfile" value="upload">
            <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload File">
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete File"><br><br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the PHP code for uploading or deleting a file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    onFunc();
}
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    offFunc();
}

function onFunc(){
    $filenameupload=__DIR__.'\\upload\\'.$_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
    if(!file_exists($filenameupload)){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'],$filenameupload);
        print_r( $_POST);
        $_POST=array();
    }
}

function offFunc(){
    $filenamedelete=__DIR__."\\upload\\".$_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
    unlink($filenamedelete);
    echo "file is deleted";
}
?>
```

The error is:

> Warning: unlink(C:\wamp64\www\IntroducingPHP\upload\Events-News.xlsx): Resource temporarily unavailable in C:\wamp64\www\IntroducingPHP\Deletefile.php on line 5

What is the solution?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: I would not expect you to have passed a file when you are doing the delete. So `$_FILES` will be empty

Comment: Also _Suggestion_ Use the Unix `\\`` in paths not the dos `/` and when you move code from windows to linux you will get less issues

Comment: The steps are:
1-I select file to upload and this is successful
2-if I press delete button directly without select file to delete the process is done and the file is deleted
3-if I select file to delete using choose file button the error is appear

Answer (score 0):

The path you mentioned has '\\'. From there and from the path mentioned in the warning it seems that you are using Windows operating system.

The file path provided to the method unlink() seems valid because the warning says the resource is temporary not available.

This means some process is having access to your file that's why it is not allowed to be deleted.

There is two possibilities :

- Are you opening the file after it is uploaded? In that case if the file is open it won't be allowed to delete it. So close it and try to delete again.
- If you've not opened the file, then there is the possibility that the variable you have used to refer to the file is still holding it.

Inside onFunc() you are using **$filenameupload** to refer the file.

If the file does not exist you upload the file and in the end you are clearing $_POST.

But the variable **$filenameupload** is not processed afterwards. So maybe it is holding the file. You add the line

```
unset($filenameupload);
```

after the if() condition inside onFunc() and check it.

This will remove the reference to the file if it is yet not removed and afterwards you may be able to delete the file.

Comment: Thanks for you help.
I  added unset($filenameupload);as you say but the error still exist.
more clarification when I select file from out side the upload folder and press delete button it works well and delete the file from inside upload folder.
I think the problem in form handler